# Collision and deflection between two balls

Tags: android, eclipse

This is a code for the movement of two balls in a rectangle.They deflect whenever they hit the wall but don't deflect when they collide with each other .Can someone help?
MovementView .java is as follows.

```
package com.example.movements;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MovementView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private int xPos,xPos1;
    private int yPos,yPos1;
    private int xVel,xVel1;
    private int yVel,yVel1;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int circleRadius,circleRadius1;
    private Paint circlePaint,circlePaint1;
    UpdateThread updateThread;

    public MovementView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        circleRadius = 10;
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        xVel = 10;
        yVel = 10;
        circleRadius1 = 10;
        circlePaint1 = new Paint();
        circlePaint1.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        xVel1 = 11;
        yVel1 = 11;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawCircle(xPos, yPos, circleRadius, circlePaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(xPos1, yPos1, circleRadius1, circlePaint1);        
    }

    public void updatePhysics() {
        xPos += xVel;
        yPos += yVel;
        if (yPos - circleRadius < 0 || yPos + circleRadius > height) {
            if (yPos - circleRadius < 0) {
                yPos = circleRadius;
            }else{
                yPos = height - circleRadius;
            }
            yVel *= -1;
        }
        if (xPos - circleRadius < 0 || xPos + circleRadius > width) {
            if (xPos - circleRadius < 0) {
                xPos = circleRadius;
            } else {
                xPos = width - circleRadius;
            }
            xVel *= -1;
        }
        xPos1 += xVel1;
        yPos1 += yVel1;
        if (yPos1 - circleRadius1 < 0 || yPos1 + circleRadius1 > height) {
            if (yPos1 - circleRadius1 < 0) {
                yPos1 = circleRadius1;
            }else{
                yPos1 = height - circleRadius1;
            }
            yVel1 *= -1;
        }
        if (xPos1 - circleRadius1 < 0 || xPos1 + circleRadius1 > width) {
            if (xPos1 - circleRadius1 < 0) {
                xPos1 = circleRadius1;
            } else {
                xPos1 = width - circleRadius1;
            }
            xVel1 *= -1;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Rect surfaceFrame = holder.getSurfaceFrame();
        width = surfaceFrame.width();
        height = surfaceFrame.height();
        xPos = width / 2;
        yPos = circleRadius;
        xPos1 = width / 2;
        yPos1 = circleRadius1;
        updateThread = new UpdateThread(this);
        updateThread.setRunning(true);
        updateThread.start();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        updateThread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                updateThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is using bounding square to the circles you have which you can easily geometrically detect collisions between, the con of using this approach is that the collision will happen when the squares hit and not the circles necessarily !

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you with the method for doing this.
Circle/circle detection is very simple, you only need to know the distance between the centers of the circles, and the radius of the circles themselves, if, you have after subtracting the radia of the circles from the length between their centers, a number smaller than their two radia added, they are intersecting.
You can deflect one balls at atime, (not physically correct) by casting a ray along its velocity vector and intersecting that with the circumference of the other circle, since you know the radius, you calculate the angle of the intersection point and then use the tangent of that point as a line from which you can calculate your new velocity vector.
It would be a good idea to move the circles "back" so that they are exactly their diameters from each other before next iteration.

Comment: thanks bro...but could you please give the coding part of it.I am trying in vain from the past 6 hours.

Comment: Thing is, an understanding of the mathematics is required in order to use the code, pasting the code would leave you no closer to a solution. While I do understand your fustration, I don't believe that you can accomplish this without sitting down and learning the dry hard math first, when you can do it on paper, you can start worrying about implementing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could test the distance between the two circles:

```
int distance = Math.sqrt( xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff );
```

The problem with this approach is if the velocity of the two balls is so fast that they can jump past each other before they collide. If you really wanted to you could check their velocity and if it is too fast then do multiple checks.

Another issue is, if you want it to be accurate then the new velocities would require you to do some trigonometry since they are circles and can bounce off each other at different angles.